# Using discord.py, want to make a hyperlink using a link that doesn't start with https://

Tags: python-3.x, url, hyperlink, discord.py

So, as the titles says, I have urls that don't start with https:// because they are direct links to iOS apps, and my problem is that if I add https:// at the beginning they links won't work, and if I don't add https:// at the beginning, discord won't recognize the links. I tried shortening the links with bitly_api, but it it just gave me errors while trying to shorten the links.

Anyone has a workaround?

EDIT: The links I get look like this cydia://url/https://cydia.saurik.com/api/share#?source=https://cydia.akemi.ai/. Those are direct links to iOS apps (in this case, Cydia). I get those links by searching for tweaks online. The code isn't the problem, the links are. If I try to put it as a hyperlink in an embed message, the link just won't work, if I try to put the title as a hyperlink, it gives me the error `discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body In embed.url: Not a well formed URL.`

EDIT 2: Tried link shorteners such as bitly_api, but then I got errors from the link shortener

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you illustrate your question with the code you have? If people can 'play' with your code, it is more likely that you'll get a quick answer.

Comment: I edited the post. I don’t think there’s a reason to post the code as well though. I just need a universal link shortener. I found is.gd and the python module, which works with cydia://, but not with installer://, sileo:// and zbra://